# Is it possible to rerun a pipeline when a specific error is returned from a proxied request?

Tags: node.js, pipeline, express-gateway

I'm using express-gateway in order to authenticate and proxy request to third party service. I want to restart the pipeline if i'm getting specific error for the proxied request.
I is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently no, there's no way to "restart" a pipeline. The only way is basically re-perform the request.

If you can explain a little bit more your use case maybe there's another solution for that. What are you trying to accomplish?